# LoadRawTextureData vs LoadImage

Tags: unity-game-engine, compression, png, jpeg, ram

I am trying to understand the expected performance difference in speed, and RAM&GPU consumption of these two in Unity. Or is it limited to [LoadRawTextureData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html) works with compressed textures whist [LoadImage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html) can't.

I was asked and I'm developing on iOS, iPadOS, Android and WebGL but I'm looking for a general answer to help me research each further later.

The use case is a user uploading multiple high-res images to the server, and then a mobile client downloading these back again.

Comment: What is your development platform?

Comment: Hi , iOS, Android and WebGL